# How to enable grid field in Acumatica - Adjustments

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

This is my code to enable the grid and enter data, but it does not work.

```
   protected void ARAdjust_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {

        ARInvoice rInvoice = Base.Document.Current;

        if (rInvoice.DocType == ARDocType.DebitMemo)
        {
            Base.Adjustments_2.AllowInsert = true;

        }
    }
```

This is the image that does not yet enable the grid.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Adjustments view is set in the primary view (DAC APInvoice) row selected event. I would override this event and add your change after calling the base method. Something like this example:

```
public class APInvoiceEntryTestExtension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    public virtual void APInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
    {
        del?.Invoke(cache, e);
        var row = (APInvoice)e.Row;
        if (row?.DocType != ARDocType.DebitMemo)
        {
            return;
        }

        Base.Adjustments.AllowInsert = true;

        //  FROM BASE CALL:
        //    Adjustments.Cache.AllowInsert = false;
        //    Adjustments.Cache.AllowDelete = false;
        //    Adjustments.Cache.AllowUpdate = !invoiceState.IsRetainageDebAdj &&
        //    invoiceState.IsDocumentRejectedOrPendingApproval || invoiceState.IsDocumentApprovedBalanced
        //        ? !invoiceState.IsDocumentRejected
        //        : Transactions.Cache.AllowUpdate && !invoiceState.IsDocumentPrebookedNotCompleted;
        }
}
```